# Adding the results of two functions in Scheme

Tags: scheme, syntax-error

I try to make a function in Scheme that adds the squares of two numbers.

```
(define (sum-of-two-squares X Y)
    (+ square(X) square(Y)))   

(sum-of-two-squares 3 5)
```

As error it tells me that "5 is not a function". How do you add the results of this two functions without giving you error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just write `(square X)` instead of `square(X)`.

In Scheme, `(X)` means *"call `X` as a function, without any arguments"*.

And `(square X)` means *"call `square` as a function, with `X` as its argument"*.

Comment: Of course! I think I'm still stuck in the Java syntax! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is:

```
(define (sum-of-two-squares X Y)
         (+ (square X) (square Y)))
```